# Locating the origin of generated dynamic SQL

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-4

I have been looking for a stored procedure that generates the dynamic sql below, which when I ran I found that it was missing extra quotation marks, otherwise it did not work.

I had to use the sql profiler to find this problematic sql code, which breaks the process of generating a report using the entity framework 4.

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT TOP (1) 
[Extent1].[InstanceId] AS [InstanceId], 
[Extent1].[AssociationId] AS [AssociationId], 
[Extent1].[Level] AS [Level], 
[Extent1].[Values] AS [Values]
FROM [dbo].[Report] AS [Extent1]
WHERE [Extent1].[InstanceId] = @p__linq__0',N'@p__linq__0 uniqueidentifier',@p__linq__0='0C550367-AFGH-425A-B7FA-559ED41EBBC2'
```

My problem is that I have no clue where to look for the stored procedure, though I am also not sure whether it may have been generated by something other than a stored proc.

Comment: Start by looking in sys.comments where TEXT like '%<sub string>%'.  See all of the procedures that may generate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

U may try like this:

```
                              SELECT NAME FROM SYS.syscomments C
            INNER JOIN sys.Objects O ON O.object_id = C.id
            where text like '%' +'Your Search Text' +'%'
```